# How to attach debugger break points between multiple processes in Android Studio/IntelliJ?

Tags: android, debugging, intellij-plugin, intellij-13

I'm an Android newbie. I tried learning about interprocess communication. I created a sample application where I created a service and made to run it on a separate process - so it would look like to me that I'm communicating with different process. Instead of this paragraph I think `AndroidManifest.xml` would give us the better picture,

```
    <activity
      android:name=".MainActivity"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
           <intent-filter>
              <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
           </intent-filter>
   </activity>

   <service
      android:name=".MyFirstService"
      android:process=":process_one" />
```

When I try to add some break points on `MainActivity` and when I keep some break point on `MyFirstService` I'm not able to. I tried on both AndroidStudio and IntelliJ but no luck.

Can someone help me on this regard please?

Comment: have you tried with "attach debugger to android process"? located in "run" tab

Comment: Even that allows me to select only one process at a time.